# Store Column Name in Variable and Return Rows Where Column is True

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables that I am trying to join in a query which requires user input. I want to store a column name from one table in a variable based on the user input, all the possible columns will be bit data type true or false. I want to return the rows from the TB_Samples table where the column stored in the variable has values of true, and join with project summary info from the TB_Projects table. Here is my code thus far:

```
DECLARE @Analysis nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @SQLQuery nvarchar(1000)
SET @Analysis = 'Elemental Analysis'
SET @SQLQuery = N'SELECT TB_Projects.JobLog#, TB_Projects .ProjName, SUM(TB_Samples.Sample#)
FROM TB_Projects INNER JOIN TB_Samples ON TB_Projects.JobLog# = TB_Samples.JobLog#
WHERE TB_Samples.[Elemental Analysis] = True GROUP BY TB_Projects.JobLog#, TB_Projects .ProjName'
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

I have the column variable hard set in my code for testing right now, I eventually want the value of this variable to be passed to SQLServer through c# in Vis Studio. The current error I receive states:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'True'."

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Try `TB_Samples.[Elemental Analysis] = 1`, assuming this is a bit column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear.  You have this line:

```
WHERE TB_Samples.[Elemental Analysis] = True
```

`True` is not a keyword in SQL Server.  Perhaps you intend:

```
WHERE TB_Samples.[Elemental Analysis] = 'True'
```

but that is just a guess.

I should note that flag columns are often stored as numbers or bits), with 0 for false and 1 for true.  So, the intention might be:

```
WHERE TB_Samples.[Elemental Analysis] = 1
```

But, if this is the case, then the column name should suggest what it really is . . . `IsElementalAnalysis` or `ElementalAnalysisFlag`.

Comment: So I think your suggestion of WHERE... = 'True' would work, but then my question would be how do I take care of the quotes part since True is already within a single quote because of how I declare @SQLQuery?

Comment: @D.Robertson . . . Perhaps you need to double up on the single quotes.  Two single quotes represent a single quote in a string.

Comment: `WHERE TB_Samples.[Elemental Analysis] = 1` works. Now when I try to use a variable reference for the column name `WHERE TB_Samples.' + @Analysis + ' = 1` in the statement a new error occurs: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Analysis'.

Comment: I just forgot my brackets: `WHERE TB_Samples.['+@Analysis+'] = 1` works. Thanks everyone for the help!